# Parse.com работает некорректно

Tags: java, android, parse.com, pushup

Пытаюсь использовать сервис *parse.com*, вроде бы все верно, но приложение работает не так как нужно.
Для своих потребностей хочу создать тестовое приложение, в котором есть возможность создать канал, подписаться на него и отписаться.

В общем приложение должно работать так:

Если я не подписался на канал, я не получаю никаких пуш вообще

1. Создаю канал
2. Подписываюсь на канал
3. Получаю пуш
4. Отписываюсь

Приложение работает так:

1. Принимает пуш уведомления с общего потока даже если я не подписался
2. Если я создаю канал с именем `123` мне выводится ошибка:

   > com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: Channel name must start with a letter: 123

   потом я пытаюсь создать канал с именем к примеру `abcd1234` но мне выводится та же ошибка:

   > com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: Channel name must start with a letter: 123
3. Если первый раз при запуске я ввел канал с нормальным именем `abcd1234` то приложение подписывается на канал и отписывается.

   ```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

           getActionBar().hide();

           statusText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusText);
           nameChanel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameChanel);
           subscribe = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.subscribe);
           unscribe = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.unscribe);

           subscribe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   if(isOnline()) {
                       if(!nameChanel.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                           subscribePush(nameChanel.getText().toString());
                           nameChanel.setText("");
                       } else {
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter name channel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                   } else {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please give me internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               }
           });

           unscribe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   if(isOnline()) {
                       unscribe();
                   } else {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter name channel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               }
           });
       }

       public void subscribePush(final String pPush) {
           hideSoftKeyboard();
           Log.e("subscribe", "subscribe");
           finalNameChanell = pPush;
           Log.e("pPush", pPush);
           Log.e("finalNameChanell subscr", finalNameChanell);

           ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(pPush, new SaveCallback() {
               @Override
               public void done(ParseException e) {
                   if (e == null) {
                       Log.e("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel. " + pPush);
                       statusText.setText("Subscribe is channel " + pPush);
                       i = 1;
                   } else {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       statusText.setText("not subscribe");
                       finalNameChanell = "";
                       Log.e("e", e.toString());
                   }
               }
           });

           ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
       }


       public void unscribe() {
           hideSoftKeyboard();
           Log.e("unscribe", "unscribe");

           if(i == 1) {
               ParsePush.unsubscribeInBackground(finalNameChanell, new SaveCallback() {
                   @Override
                   public void done(ParseException e) {
                       if (e == null) {
                           statusText.setText("not subscribe");
                           Log.e("com.parse.push", "unscribe");
                       } else {
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unscribe exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                   }
               });
               finalNameChanell = "";

               ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
               i = 0;
           } else {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You dont subscribe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }

       }
   ```